# Add for loop inside a django view

Tags: python, django, loops, for-loop

this is my django view.What it basically does is, it gets the checked data from Html view.But I have to loop through each data in the view, or in template so that I can get not only the name of subtest but also it's fields.Subtest is the name of my model,and name is it's field

```
def create_test_bills(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        selected = request.GET.getlist('selected')
        for i in range(0,len(selected)):
            a = selected [i]
            print(selected)
            print(a)
            sub_test = Subtest.objects.filter(name=a)
    return render(request,'report.html',{'sub_test':sub_test})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use django filter `__in` 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#in

instead of looping through it:

```
def create_test_bills(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        selected = request.GET.getlist('selected')
        if len(selected) > 0:
           sub_test = Subtest.objects.filter(name__in=selected)
    return render(request,'report.html',{'sub_test':sub_test})
```

Comment: I think you can skip the loop altogether, just use `Subtest.objects.filter(name__in=selected)`

Comment: @ruddra yeah i think so too i wrote like that as i'm not certain what getList return

Comment: it returns a list :)

Comment: oh, note taken :)